# Reducing threshold p-value in case of statistical tests following data exploration

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, methodology

Imagine, I got a new dataset. I look into it, trying to find a plausible hypothesis. During this I build charts, trying to find something interesting. Should I reduce the p-value threshold due to multiple hypothesis tests like with Bonferroni correction.

Intuitively, I feel that I should since even in cases of drawing charts, I in fact do some kind of hypothesis testing. However, I wasn't able to find anything relevant about this.

What should be done in such a case?

Comment: Andrew Gelman calls this "researcher degrees of freedom", or "the garden of forking paths"; do take a look at the paper. You don't find anything because systematizing p value correction for this kind of highly non-standard process is pretty much impossible.  If at all, them divide your dataset in two *first*, then do whatever EDA you want with the first half, and finally do NHST only on the second half.

Comment: Just keep in mind that split sample validation requires huge samples sizes to be stable and precise.  I.e., if the the training an test samples are not both extremely large you may be surprised how different the answers are when you split again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

##### Peeking at Data

I don't think you have any business tinkering around with $p$ values if you are doing exploratory data analysis, as this can be a form of hypothesizing after results are known (HARKing, Kerr, 1998; Chambers, 2017). Unless you had some strong a priori hypothesis for what your data was supposed to look like, it's not entirely scientific to set up a falsifiable probability model when you have basically already peeked at the data beforehand. The assumption is usually that the data hasn't been observed yet.

That is not to say that doing an exploratory data analysis isn't useful. By all means, it can be very informative. I just don't think you can generate reports of "discovered relationships" that you didn't intend on finding in the first place.

##### References

- Chambers, C. (2017). The seven deadly sins of psychology a manifesto for reforming the culture of scientific practice. Princeton University Press.
- Kerr, N. L. (1998). HARKing: Hypothesizing after the results are known. Personality and Social Psychology Review, 2(3), 196-217.

Answer (score 5):

This is one case where even I, p value skeptic that I am, find some use for them. But not if you do what you did.

In my work, it was never the case that we just "got some data" and went looking for things. Both when I was employed (at a research company, a hospital, and so on) or when I was a consultant and got hired by researchers,  we first got a hypothesis and then went and got data. Often we were almost certain that the null was false. (This makes me want to look at the references Shawn gave, I will try to do so later).

For stuff in psychology and many other fields, I'm more of a fan of Paul Meehl, e.g.
Meehl, Paul E. (1978). "Theoretical risks and tabular asterisks: Sir Karl, Sir Ronald, and the slow progress of soft psychology" (PDF). Journal of Consulting and Clinical Psychology. 46 (4): 806–834. doi:10.1037/0022-006x.46.4.806. Reprinted in Meehl 1991, pp. 1–43 and Waller et al. 2006, pp. 57–90.

and other papers.

But you are, apparently, getting the data first. Maybe you found it on the web. And now you are just looking. Now you need a p value cutoff. Because you're really just sort of randomly guessing. Even if you adjust the p value somehow, this is an example of the "Texas sharpshooter paradox" where someone shoots at a barn door and then paints targets around the holes.

Here, you have to be very careful and follow the rules. First explore, then test, on a different data set. Alternatively, you can divide your data into train and test (and maybe validate); this has been written about a lot here.

EDIT: Having quickly read Kerr's article, I must say I am not an advocate of HARKing, exactly, rather, I am an advocate of avoiding the problem by not presenting p values. I do like Kerr's analysis of the many pressures on researchers that may lead them to do bad things. Another thing I am an advocate of is publishing protocol papers (similar to the proposal stage of a dissertation) and then having the journal agree to publish results, if the protocol is followed, regardless of what those results are.

Answer (score 3):

Exploratory and preliminary, hypothesis generating research should not use a p-value cutoff for any decision other than to test the hypothesis with new data or to put it aside. You simply cannot test a hypothesis with the data that originally suggested the hypothesis because the data will favour that hypothesis whether or not the hypothesis is true. Otherwise the data would not have suggested the hypothesis.